# Handling 404 via Maybe in http-conduit

Tags: haskell, http-conduit

Using [`http-conduit`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-conduit) I want to download a HTTP URL implementing the following semantics (resulting in `IO (Maybe LB.ByteString)` ):

1. If the HTTP response code is 2xx, return `Just` the response body
2. If the HTTP response code is 404, return `Nothing`
3. If the response code indicates a redirect, follow according to standard http-conduit settings
4. For any other response code, throw a `StatusCodeException`.

How can I do that using `httpLbs` without any libraries beyond `http-conduit` and its dependencies?

Note: This question was answered in Q&A form and therefore intentionally does not show research effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible by using a custom `checkStatus` similar to one of the [offical examples](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-conduit/docs/Network-HTTP-Conduit.html).

We will declare `checkStatus200` which passes if the response status code is either 2xx or 404. If it doesn't pass, it calls the default `checkStatus` function to throw the appropriate exception.

After calling `httpLbs` with a `Request` using `checkStatus200`, we can check the status code and return either `Just` the response code or `Nothing`.

```haskell
import Data.Conduit.Binary (sinkFile)
import Network.HTTP.Types.Status (Status(..))
import Network.HTTP.Conduit
import qualified Data.Conduit as C
import Network
import Data.Default (def)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as LB

-- | @checkStatus@ implementation that accepts 
--   2xx status codes and 404. Calls default implementation
--   on other status codes (i.e. throws exception)
checkStatus200 st@(Status sc _) rh cj =
    if (200 <= sc && sc < 300) || sc == 404
        then Nothing
        else (checkStatus def) st rh cj

-- | Download a HTTP link, returning @Nothing@ on 404 status code
downloadCatch404 :: String
                 -> IO (Maybe LB.ByteString)
downloadCatch404 url = withSocketsDo $ do
    request <- parseUrl url
    let request' = request { checkStatus = checkStatus200 }
    res <- withManager $ httpLbs request'
    let status =  statusCode . responseStatus $ res
    -- Return Nothing if status code == 404
    return $ if status == 404
        then Nothing
        else Just $ responseBody res
```